# New to C# and can't make a Multidimensional Array

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

Hi i am moving to c# now from VBS and .net this is my first attempt at making anything in C# so it is a very basic question. How do i make an array?

Below is my current attempt

```
        string[] arr1 = new string[1, 2];
        arr1[0, 0] = "One";
        arr1[0, 1] = "two";
        arr1[0, 2] = "three";
        arr1[1, 0] = "four";
        arr1[1, 1] = "five";
        arr1[1, 2] = "six";
```

Comment: Use `string[,] arr1` instead of `string[] arr1`.

Comment: `string[,] arr1 = new string[2, 3];` Note comma on left side and dimentions on the right

Comment: For this example, the declaration should be `string[,] arr1 = new string[1,2];` : the comma must appear both in the declaration and in the definition of the array. Also, the numbers inside the squared brackets mean the amount of element. In your example, you only have one element of each two elements in your array : `arr1[0,0]="One"; arr1[0,1]="Two"`

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx

Comment: adding the comma in the declaration worked great, Thanks

Comment: @Tyagi i know about MSDN first place i went as i used to do VBS but it can sometimes make things more confusing :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your declaration: `string[] arr1 = new string[1, 2];` You are trying to asign a 2 dimensional array to a one dimensional array. The proper declaration would be:
`string[,] arr1 = new string[1, 2]; //notice the , in the declaration`

Furthermore, you have defined your first dimension with a length of 1 and your second with a length of 2, while in your code:

```
arr1[1, 0] = "four";
arr1[1, 1] = "five";
arr1[1, 2] = "six";
```

You are treating it as if your first dimension had a length of 2 and your second as if it had a length of 3. This will throw an exception.

Answer (score 2):

There is a site named MSDN :D , You can find all basic syntax related stuffs with detailed examples there :D ,
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx

Comment: as i am new sometimes MSDN makes it harder to understand, checked that article out before :)

Answer (score 1):

The array you declared has one row and two columns and you are trying to access two rows and three columns. With your code you will get exception. You also need a comma for two dimension on left side. You can read more about using multi-dimension [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx).

```
string[,] arr1 = new string[1, 2];
arr1[0, 0] = "One";
arr1[0, 1] = "two";
```

Comment: but i thought arrays where zero based so this was possible?

Comment: @Kieranmv95: Yes, they're zero-based - but the `new string[1, 2]` gives the *length* of each dimension, not an inclusive upper bound.

Comment: It is zero based, if you give the size 1 then it will have only one element at index zero. In you case first dimension is 1 so one row and second dimension is 2 so two columns